# Does Blender have any plugins, addons or libraries for dealing with skulls and bones or full skeletons?

Tags: add-on, library

Are there any official or unofficial addons, plugins or asset libraries in blender that relate to human or animal bones, skulls, or full skeletons?

For example, human or animal skeletons that can be used to make procedurally generated piles of bones in a render of a dungeon or a monster's nest. Or libraries of skulls and other bones.

Or does it have any textures and maps relating to bones in various states of decay?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are.  Here is one of my favorites, ["Anotated Skeleton Model"](https://blenderpirate.gumroad.com/l/lAqVE) by Jeannot Landry (Blender Pirate on twitter.)  There is a free version. He developed this with the help of an anatomist and it is quite accurate. He has also done a horse skeleton that's fairly accurate.

There is also [Z-Anatomy](https://www.z-anatomy.com/) which is not strictly for Blender, but you can use their database in Blender models and there are tutorials.

And, of course there are any number of skeleton models on Blender market or Sketchfab.